# angularjs Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I am trying to create some events in a dynamic input

**This is the HTML code**

```
<input id="{{inputField.id}}"
 placeholder="{{inputField.placeHolder}}"
 ng-readonly="(!identificationProperty.allowManualInput && inputField.binding == identificationProperty.binding) || inputField.isReadOnly"
 type="number"
 size="15"
 min="{{inputField.minLength}}"
 maxLength="{{(inputField.maxLength ? inputField.maxLength : 120)}}"
 class="form-control"
 ng-model="model[inputField.binding]"
 value="{{ model[inputField.binding] || 0 }}"
 name="{{inputField.binding}}"
 data-toggle="tooltip"
 title="{{inputField.placeHolder}}"
 bind-events="events | filter: {name:inputField.binding}: true"
 step="{{inputField.isDecimal ? 0.01 : 1}}" />
```

**This is the controller**

```
angular.module('app').
controller('519', ['$scope', '$ftHttp', 'ngToast', '$location', function ($scope, $ftHttp, ngToast, $location) {

    $scope.metadataPath = '/proxy/metadata/519';

    change = function() {
        var amount = $scope.viewData.model.amount ? $scope.viewData.model.amount : 0;
        var taxesValue = $scope.viewData.model.taxesValue ? $scope.viewData.model.taxesValue : 0;
        var additionalValue = $scope.viewData.model.additionalValue ? $scope.viewData.model.additionalValue : 0;
        var discountValue = $scope.viewData.model.discountValue ? $scope.viewData.model.discountValue : 0;

        $scope.viewData.model.netValue = amount + taxesValue + additionalValue - discountValue;
    }


    $scope.events = [
        {
            'name': 'amount',
            'event': 'change',
            'action': function(){
                change();
            }
        },
        {
            'name': 'taxesValue',
            'event': 'change',
            'action': function(){
                if($scope.viewData.model.taxesValue && $scope.viewData.model.taxesValue != 0) {
                    change();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'name': 'additionalValue',
            'event': 'change',
            'action': function(){
                if($scope.viewData.model.additionalValue && $scope.viewData.model.additionalValue != 0) {
                    change();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'name': 'discountValue',
            'event': 'change',
            'action': function(){
                if($scope.viewData.model.discountValue && $scope.viewData.model.discountValue != 0) {
                    change();
                }
            }
        }
    ];

    $scope.getMyScope = function () {
        return $scope;
    };

    $scope.afterAddNew = function (model) {
        model['issuanceDate'] = new Date();
    };

}]);
```

**And this is the directive**

```
angular.module('components')
 .directive('bindEvents', function () {
return {
    scope: {
        bindEvents: '='
    },
    link(scope, element) {
        if (!scope.bindEvents) {
            return;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < scope.bindEvents.length; i++) {
            element.on(scope.bindEvents[i].event, scope.bindEvents[i].action);
        }
    }
};})
```

Everything works perfectly fine without the pagination directive. However with my new directive as soon as I load the page I get a [$rootScope:infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) error which I don't understand since the directive is not doing anything to manipulate data that could end up in an infinite loop.
What is the problem here and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: the bind-events directive***

Comment: try to log the change(); calls, something is unstable

Comment: sorry i put the full controller now

Answer (score 3):

Just put = * in the directive

```
angular.module('components')
 .directive('bindEvents', function () {
return {
    scope: {
        bindEvents: '=*'
    },
    link(scope, element) {
        if (!scope.bindEvents) {
            return;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < scope.bindEvents.length; i++) {
            element.on(scope.bindEvents[i].event, scope.bindEvents[i].action);
        }
    }
};})
```